# tensorflow estimator evaluate much slower than training

Tags: tensorflow, evaluate

I have a custom estimator and am trying to use some custom metrics during evaluation. However, whenever I add these metrics to evaluation, via eval_metric_ops the evaluation becomes really slow (much slower than training which is actually calculating the same metrics). If I don't add the metrics there then I can only see metrics in Tensorboard for training and not for evaluation.

What is the right way to add a custom metric for a custom estimator so that it is saved during evaluation.

This is what I have:

```
def compute_accuracy(preds, labels):
    total = tf.shape(labels.values)[0]
    preds = tf.sparse_to_dense(preds.indices, preds.dense_shape, preds.values, default_value=-1)
    labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(labels.indices, labels.dense_shape, labels.values, default_value=-2)

    r = tf.shape(labels)[0]
    c = tf.minimum(tf.shape(labels)[1], tf.shape(preds)[1])
    preds = tf.slice(preds, [0,0], [r,c])
    labels = tf.slice(labels, [0,0], [r,c])

    preds = tf.cast(preds, tf.int32)
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int32)

    correct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(preds, labels), tf.int32))
    accuracy = tf.divide(correct, total)
    return accuracy

In model_fn
    edit_dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(predicted_label[0], tf.int32), labels))
    accuracy = compute_accuracy(predicted_label[0], labels)
    tf.summary.scalar('edit_dist', edit_dist)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

    metrics = {
        'accuracy': tf.metrics.mean(accuracy),
        'edit_dist':tf.metrics.mean(edit_dist),
    }

   if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
```

As requested, here is the complete model and TfRecord Writer code:

```
def crnn_model(features, labels, mode, params):

    inputs = features['image']
    print("INPUTS SHAPE", inputs.shape)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        batch_size = params['batch_size']
        lr_initial = params['lr']
        lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(lr_initial, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),
                                        decay_steps=params['lr_decay_steps'], decay_rate=params['lr_decay_rate'],
                                        staircase=True)
        tf.summary.scalar('lr', lr)
    else:
        batch_size = params['test_batch_size']

    with tf.variable_scope('crnn', reuse=False):
        rnn_output, predicted_label, logits = CRNN(inputs, hidden_size=params['hidden_size'], batch_size=batch_size)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {
            'predicted_label': predicted_label,
            'logits': logits,
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)


    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=labels, inputs=rnn_output,
                                         sequence_length=23 * np.ones(batch_size),
                                         ignore_longer_outputs_than_inputs=True))
    edit_dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(predicted_label[0], tf.int32), labels))
    accuracy = compute_accuracy(predicted_label[0], labels)

    metrics = {
        'accuracy': tf.metrics.mean(accuracy),
        'edit_dist':tf.metrics.mean(edit_dist),
    }

    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('edit_dist', edit_dist)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Tf Record Writer code

```
def _write_fn(self, out_file, image_list, label_list, mode):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_file)
    N = len(image_list)
    for i in range(N):
        if (i % 1000) == 0:
            print('%s Data: %d/%d records saved' % (mode, i,N))
            sys.stdout.flush()

        try:
            #print('Try image: ', image_list[i])
            image = load_image(image_list[i])
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            print('Ignoring image: ', image_list[i])
            continue
        label = label_list[i]
        feature = {
            'label': _int64_feature(label),
            'image': _byte_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image.tostring()))
        }

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

Comment: I guess you solved your problem in the mean time, but I edited my answer for anyone with similar symptoms

Answer (score 2):

In the Estimator framework, everything happens in the `model_fn`, namely your `crnn_model(features, labels, mode, params)`. This is why this function has such a complex signature.

The `mode` parameter indicates whether it is called for training, evaluation or prediction. So, if you want to log additional summaries to tensorboard during the evaluation, you would add them under the `if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL` section, or outside any `if` in the `model_fn`.

<s>I suppose your eval is much slower because you have different batch sizes for train/eval and the eval batch size could be smaller.</s>  You indicated this is not the case.

After a closer look at your code, and having experienced with a similar model, I believe that the evaluation takes longer with metrics because one of the metrics is `edit_distance()` which is implemented sequentially on the CPU. During training, this `op` is not required so it is not run.

What I suggest is that you run your `train()` and `evaluate()` in different programs, with the same `model_fn()` and `model_dir`. This way, `train` does not need to wait for `evaluate`. And `evaluate` will run only when necessary, i.e. when there are new checkpoints in the `model_dir`. If you don't have 2 GPUs for this, you can either split the GPU memory between the two processes (using a custom run-config with `gpu_memory_fraction=0.75` for train) or by hiding the GPU from `evaluate()` with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''` environment variable

Comment: The code for metrics passed to eval_metrics_ops are just above it metrics = {
        'accuracy': tf.metrics.mean(accuracy),
        'edit_dist':tf.metrics.mean(edit_dist),
    }
        
The evaluation takes longer than training when using metrics even with same batch size for both training and evaluation.

Comment: does the evaluate support distributed itself? e.g using multiple nodes to do evaluate

Comment: @crafet I don't know. Consider asking a new question, as yours is not related to this one